# How much does Bell Clapper's deformity increase the chance of testicular torsion?

Tags: testicles, cotton-balls

A [bell clapper deformity](http://www.meddean.luc.edu/lumen/meded/urology/bellclap.htm) is a condition where a testicle is not anchored in the scrotum, but is able to move freely (Much like the clapper in a bell, hence the name).

If a person suffers from this deformity, is it more likely that they will develop testicular torsion, and if so, what is the increased chances that this will occur?

Comment: I edited it to make it a little more generic and informative. You can roll it back if you don't agree with the edit.